# Condition syntax: "when equal to any of"

Tags: conditional, expression-test

I am trying to write a condition clause for a certain expression. I need to pick out the following cases:

> Mod[x*y, 10] == 8, or
>
> Mod[x*y, 10] == 3, or
>
> Mod[x*y, 10] == 7.

I need to repeat this three times, and both `x` and `y` are actually complex expressions, so it would be nice to be able to write this in a compact way.

I have tried

```
Mod[x*y, 10] == Or[8,3,7]
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any of the following:

```
MatchQ[Mod[x y, 10], 8 | 3 | 7]
MemberQ[{8, 3, 7}, Mod[x y, 10]]
AnyTrue[{8, 3, 7}, Mod[x y, 10] == # &]
Or @@ (Mod[x y, 10] == # & /@ {8, 3, 7})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method that's quite close to what you tried at first:

```
Thread[Mod[x*y, 10] == Or[8, 3, 7], Or]
```

Note, however, that this won't work if any of the arguments of `Or` are boolean since this method relies on `Or` not evaluating.